# how to remove 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'nodeValue' error in Python

Tags: python, xml

I am trying to retrieve all the values in the XML file posted. Whenever i execute my code, i keep getting, `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'nodeValue`' whenever there is an empty tag in XML file. Can anyone tell me the code in python to retrieve all the values Including `Empty tag as ""` value

The XML file is given below:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Setting>
    <fName>abc</fName>
        <mName></mName>
    <lName>xyz</lName>    
</Setting>
```

here is my python code:

```
readDoc = minidom.parseString(myXmlstring)

mn = readDoc.getElementsByTagName("mName")
```

Comment: What are you using to parse the xml file?

Comment: I don't get any error with the text and code you posted.

Comment: I had edited  the question with python code

Comment: @madan your code works on my environment. You should submit code that fails with the error you described or give us more precision on your environment (python version, ...).